# Supersaturated conversion of sodium acetate utilizing electricity

Tags: organic-chemistry, thermodynamics, electrochemistry

Is it possible to use electricity to take crystallized sodium acetate back to a supersaturated solution?

Comment: Well if you have a solution which has crystallized sodium acetate, then putting it on a hot plate will heat the solution and dissolve more sodium acetate. You can't keep the same temperature of solution and "persuade" more solid sodium acetate to dissolve into a saturated solution by passing an electric current through the solution.

Comment: You could use a microwave oven. which *does* pass electricity through the sodium acetate, but that's just a variation on @MaxW's answer.

Comment: A microwave oven wouldn't pass electricity in a sodium acetate solution. The microwaves would cause the water molecules to rotate and hence heat the liquid. The solid would be heated some, but not much. Ice doesn't absorb microwaves as well as water.

Comment: The microwaves can create a current in metal. So if you have a plate with a silver or gold band around the rim, then using it in the microwave will create a current in the metal band. In fact it will heat such a metal band so much that it will destroy the band.

Comment: What about using ultrasound to excite the crystal structure? Or another type of radiant heat?

Comment: @Johnny-V - Since you seemed determined to find an interaction I'll mention liquid crystals. In the presence of an electric field (like a capacitor, not actually current passing through crystals) the liquid crystal can "dissolve." Sodium acetate isn't such a molecule.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_crystal